Не получается преобразовать в int и посчитать
У меня есть TextBlock'и который выводит ячейку с суммой товара, в зависимости от того, какой товар будет выбран в Combobox'е. Например: <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Processors}" x:Name="ProcessorC"> и <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ProcessorC, Path=SelectedItem.Price}" Grid.Row="7" x:Name="PrSumma">.
У меня несколько таких Combobox'ов и TextBlock'ов. Как видно в коде, я даю TextBlock'у параметр x:Name, и у остальных TextBlock'ов, тоже есть этот параметр.
Дело в том, что я хотел сделать ещё один TextBlock, в котором будет сумма всех чисел, пытался написать код таким образом:
var PrPrice = PrSumma;
var CSPrice = CSSumma;
var MbPrice = MbSumma;
var RAMPrice = RAMSumma;
var VCPrice = VCSumma;
var PUPrice = PUSumma;
var CoPrice = CoSumma;
var TPPrice = TPSumma;
var MiPrice = MiSumma;
var KbPrice = KbSumma;
var CaPrice = CaSumma;
var HphPrice = HphSumma;
var HDDPrice = HDDSumma;
var SSDPrice = SSDSumma;
var JoyPrice = JoySumma;
var MoPrice = MoSumma;

int[] sumi = { PrPrice, CSPrice, MbPrice, RAMPrice, VCPrice, PUPrice, CoPrice, TPPrice, 
MiPrice, KbPrice, CaPrice, HphPrice, HDDPrice, SSDPrice, JoyPrice, MoPrice };

var SUM = sumi.Sum();
Summa.Text = Convert.ToString(SUM);

Я сделал переменный на каждый TextBlock, и присвоил их, затем добавил их всех в массив и с помощью var SUM = sumi.Sum(); сделал сумму всех чисел в массиве, и вывел всё это в новый TextBlock - Summa.
Но у меня возникла ошибка в поле:
int[] sumi = { PrPrice, CSPrice, MbPrice, RAMPrice, VCPrice, PUPrice, CoPrice, TPPrice, 
MiPrice, KbPrice, CaPrice, HphPrice, HDDPrice, SSDPrice, JoyPrice, MoPrice };

Ошибка следующая:

Не удается неявно преобразовать тип
"System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" в "int".

Я по искал в интернете и понял что нужно преобразовать все переменные в int, я так и сделал, но ничего не получилось, я пробовал Convert.ToInt32(PrSumma); и int.Parse(PrSumma.Text); и переводил в double и во всё что можно, но возникала другая ошибка:

Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" к
типу "System.IConvertible"."

а также ошибка:

System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Я пытался найти  решение, но не получилась не моими силами в коде, не моими силами в поиске в интрнете, по этому прошу помощи у вас.

Вы совершенно все делаете не так. 1. Если у вас куча переменных, то это явно должен быть массив, а не как у вас набор бессмысленных переменных. 2. В WPF самое важное и самое базовое, это привязки и XAML, другими словами, у вас не должно быть в коде обращение через x:Name контрола. У вас должно быть свойство с нужным типом к которому идет привязка нужного контрола, все, этого достаточно. 3. Вы забываете про ООП, ибо всякие "SSD", "RAM", и др. параметры у вас должны быть в виде отдельных объектов, которые имеют внутри описание, название, цену, и т.д., а у вас набор переменных...

Что касается ошибок - займитесь отладкой, это основной инструмент программиста, которым вы обязаны уметь пользоваться. Поставьте точку остановки перед конвертацией и посмотрите, что вы передаете, так вы поймете, почему вдруг "Входная строка имела неверный формат". Что касается других ошибок, то сами подумайте, вы в int пытаетесь засунуть TextBlock, не кажется странным? Далее ToInt32(PrSumma); - что за тип у PrSumma? Очевидно, это не текст, а сам контрол, ну так чего вы собрались там конвертировать? Вот int.Parse(PrSumma.Text) уже правильно, занимайтесь теперь отладкой.

И да, советую задуматься о рейтинге на SO, ибо SO это не форум, а сайт, где сообщество совместными усилиями собирает полезную не только вам (автору) информацию, но и будущим читателям. Задавая вот так вопросы, не доводя их до конца, вы рискуете получить блокировку от системы. Например вон у вас есть вопрос с ответом, примите его (галка слева), остальные вовсе без ответов (если вы нашли ответ, то опубликуйте его). Но это так, совет...

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ - рекомендую, сам с этих уроков начинал учиться
